# access sql errors

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT m_num,m_genre,m_cost,newcost
from movire q,
(select avg(m_cost) as newcost,m_genre
from movire 
group by m_genre) b
where q.m_genre=b.m_genre ;
```

> m_genre could refer to one more table listed in the from clause

What is the problem?

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  Both tables in the FROM clause contain a column named `m_genre` . The database doesn't know which one you want when you use `SELECT m_genre, .....`. Prefix the column with the desired table alias `q` or `b`.

Comment: It looks to me that you want to retrieve details of each movie plus the average cost of making a movie of that particular genre. Is that correct?

Comment: The message is a little bit confusing because there is one table only. The sub query in brackets is no table, but a result set from a table (and here from the identic table as before). But you need to specify whether to use the m_genre from the table itself or from your sub query.

Comment: Are you using [Microsoft Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access)?

Comment: i successfully fixed it by adding b. in front of m_genre thank you

Comment: `because there is one table only`  @JonasMetzler - There's one *physical* table, but the FROM clause references two tables: one physical and one "derived table" i.e. what you're calling a subquery.

Comment: That's clear, I called it result set ;)

Comment: @JonasMetzler - Heh, true enough!